# syntax error at or near "{" using rails in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Below query is working in Mysql,but its not working in postgresql.

```
Campaign.scheduled_with_community_ids(community_ids).
        joins(:community).
        order('FIELD(campaigns.id, #{editable_ids}) DESC').
        order(:launch_date, 'communities.community_name')
```

am getting below error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{" LINE 2: ...s" = 's_approved')) ORDER BY FIELD(campaigns.id, #{editable_...
```

Please anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

You should use double-quoted strings when you want to use interpolation:

```
Campaign.scheduled_with_community_ids(community_ids).
    joins(:community).
    order("FIELD(campaigns.id, #{editable_ids}) DESC").
    order(:launch_date, 'communities.community_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `single qoute` try `double qoute`:

```
Campaign.scheduled_with_community_ids(community_ids).
    joins(:community).
    order("FIELD(campaigns.id, #{editable_ids}) DESC").
    order(:launch_date, 'communities.community_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
Campaign.scheduled_with_community_ids(community_ids).
        joins(:community).
        order('FIELD(campaigns.id, #{editable_ids}) DESC').
        order(:launch_date, 'communities.community_name')
```

to this

```
Campaign.scheduled_with_community_ids(community_ids).
        joins(:community).
        order("FIELD(campaigns.id, #{editable_ids}) DESC").
        order(:launch_date, 'communities.community_name')
```

You have to use double quotes to be able to interpolate

Comment: Okay even though i got some different error
--------------

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function field(bigint, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 2: ...OR "campaigns"."status" = 's_approved')) ORDER BY FIELD(camp...

Comment: Could you update the question and explain more what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Campaign.scheduled_with_community_ids(community_ids).
    joins(:community).
    order("FIELD(campaigns.id, #{editable_ids}) DESC").
    order(:launch_date, 'communities.community_name')


-----------------------

but am getting this error

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function field(bigint, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 2: ...OR "campaigns"."status" = 's_approved')) ORDER BY FIELD(camp...

Comment: I think **Postgresql** doesn't have a `field()` **function**, and if it has you have to activate it first.